# How to connect to remote DB in local phpMyAdmin (WAMP)?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, remote-access, local-database, remote-connection

I'm using `WAMP` server with `MySQL Version : 5.6.17`.
Is there a way to connect to remote DB from my local phpMyAdmin?

I have credentials for remote database, but I can not find a way how to add a connection in my local panel.

I found over the new that it is something related to some `config file`, or something called `PMA`, but couldn't found more details about it.

Comment: http://tecadmin.net/add-multiple-hosts-in-phpmyadmin/# this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

In `config.inc.php` under your phpMyAdmin folder, change the value of `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` from `'localhost'` to the ip address of your remote DB.

See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_host for details.